# Get specific related model field in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get some specif fields of an eloquent model and its relation. My hotel table is related to city

```
// Hotel model

public function City() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
}
```

In controller

```
data = Hotel::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
        ->with( array( 'city' => function($query){
                 $query->select('cities.description');
            })
        )
        ->get(array('hotels.id', 'hotels.name', 'hotels.description as desc'));
```

it returns the city field as null

```
{
 id: 3
 name: "hotel one"
 desc: "lorem ipsum"
 city: null
},
{
 id: 4
 name: "hotel two"
 desc: "lorem ipsum"
 city: null
}
```

If I use get() instead of get with parameters it returns the city parameters. Am I doing it in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issues. I had to get the foreign key `city_id` from the hotel.

```
data = Hotel::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
    ->with( array( 'city' => function($query){
             $query->select( array('cities.id', 'cities.description'));
        })
    )
    ->get(array('hotels.id', 'city_id', 'hotels.name', 'hotels.description as desc'));
```

For other models like country and state laravel were merging the model with out specifying the foreign key. For cities table the default foreign key ware not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do following. I don't think there will be significant performance gain in selecting just one field, on modern hardware.

```
$hotel = Hotel::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")->first();
echo $hotel->id;
echo $hotel->name;
echo $hotel->description;
echo $hotel->city->description;
```

**UPDATE**

Please try following if you want to select fields

```
$posts = Hotel::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
         ->with(array('city' => function($query)
         {
             // Notice that you add either the primary key or the
             // foreign key to the field list, or else Laravel
             // won't be able to link the models together!
             $query->addSelect(array('id', 'description'));
         }))
        ->get(array('hotels.id', 'hotels.name', 'hotels.description as desc'));
```

Comment: It will fetch all the fields from hotel stable and cities table, but I want  to fetch only specific fields so that the query time will be less

Comment: Don't worry about query time unless you are building something that is going to get heavy traffic . As I said on Modern Hardware With PHP 5.5 or above, this will be unnoticeable. So this hard-work to get single field will not pay off.

Comment: My hotel model has a lot of relations city, state, country, user, price, tags, testimonial etc.. its not a good idea to fetch all the fields of these tables along with each hotel detail when I perform a seach. I only want one field from each table ie, city name from city, state name,etc.. but each of these table has more than 10 fields

Comment: I have updated my answer based on http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/column-selection-in-eager-loading

Comment: Still  the same result